# Can't get ESM to work with Knex CLI v0.21.5

Tags: javascript, knex.js, es6-modules, nvm, npx

When running:

```
npx knex migrate:latest
```

I get this error:

[image: error]

What is this `.npm` directory for in `/home/raj/.npm/_npx/8138/lib/node_modules/knex/lib/util/import-file.js` ? Is it some cache that can be deleted?

I updated Knex to 0.21.5 so it could work with `"type":"module"` set in my `package.json` for ESM syntax, but I still get this complaint. My node.js project uses `import` statements, not `require()` calls, so confused about what is causing this. Additionally, Knex's command line tool is also updated to the latest:

[image: versions]

Might it still have something to do with Knex's command line tool? Some `nvm` or `npx` cache? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It's because for ESM to work, the command needs to be run with an `--esm` argument:

```sh
npx knex --esm migrate:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

My project is defined with `"type": "module"` in `package.json`
Therefore I renamed `knexfile.js` to `knexfile.cjs`

Here is the full command

```
npx knex --esm --knexfile knexfile.cjs migrate:make my_migration
```

This will produce a migration file `my_migration.cjs`